# Get calling app name from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am building an application which handles GET_CONTENT intents via an intent filter.

When my app receives an intent, I would like to know the name of the app who originated it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that information is not included in the `Intent`. You can try calling [`Binder.getCallingUid()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#getCallingUid%28%29), and see if that returns the other app.